# Adding a new character and setting position on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I need to do the following but haven't figured out how at the moment:

I have an `<input type="text">` i need to add the **"-"** right after the user typed the first character, and put the cursor on the next position on the length, (the 3rd position) so the user can continue typing

For instance:

"G- <--- add this "-" sign with jQuery and set the cursor right after it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is my current code.

```
$('#document').keypress(function(e){
    if(this.value.length == 1){     
               $(this).val($(this).val() + '-');
            }
});
```

It adds the "-" sign but to after the user types.

I want that right after the user types the first character the "-" character is added to the string. so far if i type "H" i get "-H" and i want "H-".

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: You should do this after the user has already entered the whole string. Have an event fire when the input loses focus, then check for input and edit it. Also, Show what you have tried by yourself

Comment: so far on the `.keypress` event just checked the length of the string using `this.value.length` but every time i try to add the "-" character to the input it replaces the current content, i'm not sure how to append it to the end of the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
you also need to check if key is backspace or not. if it is backspace then you should skip this event.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/32/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#my-input").keypress(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode != 8){ //check for backspace press
        var text = this.value;
        if(text.length ==1){
           this.value=text+'-'; 
         }
        }
     });
});
```

UPDATE:
 If user type '-' and input field has more than one '-' character then until he is deleting this '-' it not allows user to input other character
http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/42/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#my-input").keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode !=46) {
         var text = this.value;
        if(text.split("-").length > 2){ // check for double -
            alert("already exixts");
            return false;
         }       
        if(text.length ==1){
           this.value=text+'-'; 
         }
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Works, but then i cant delete the first letter, what if the user wants to change the first letter?

Comment: Yes, its working, one last thing if you can help me, what if i want to accept only one character before the "-" sign so if the user puts the cursor before it and there is already one character there, then the function return false

Comment: Actually, @AwladLiton, wouldn't you want to leave the event in on a backspace?  If they delete the "-" after it's inserted, it would need to be placed back in.

Also, this logic can be circumvented by pasting in a value that has a length greater than 1.

Comment: @Enoba Sistemas: oaky i am updating my answer

Comment: @talemyn i disabled "copy paste" from the inputbox so its not an issue, i need the user to actually type the string.

Comment: @EnobaSistemas - did you completely disable the event, or just block the `paste` keycode?  Just making sure that browser menus and context menus are covered as well . . .

Comment: @talemyn yes, i disabled the menus and context too, at least for the regular user wont be easy to do anything.

Comment: @AwladLiton I think i didn't explained myself properly, however i accepted your answer because it does what i was looking for, anyway i just need that if i type "H" and the hyphen gets added "H-" if the user puts the cursor after the hyphen he cant add more than 1 character before it, so he will not end having "HDFG-" that cannot be allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try have a look at this plugin : https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a event handler to your input field.
In that handler you could add a `-` after the user entered the first letter.
Please note that you have to use jQuery for this to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id-of-input').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).length == 1) $(this).val($(this).val() + "-"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this Jquery script:

[meioMask](http://jquery-plugins.net/meiomask-jquery-mask-plugin)

[meioMask - GitHub](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn4vV/6/

```
$( "input" ).keyup(function(e) {
    if( $(this).val().length == 1  && (e.keyCode != 8) &&  (e.keyCode != 46))
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '-');    
});
```

Edit: updated my answer to deal with backspace and delete keys

Comment: So far this one is doing the trick, but go and try to delete and see what happens when you reach the length == 1

Comment: It's not a complete solution, it's just an answer to your question. You still need to cover del/backspace, cut/paste and drag/drop. This will handle del and backspace buttons for example `if( $(this).val().length == 1  && (e.keyCode != 8) &&  (e.keyCode != 46))` http://jsfiddle.net/Jn4vV/6/

Comment: @Awlad Liton was more closer to what i wanted, but your solution is fine, so i upvoted you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my take at it.   :)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="addDashField" />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addDashField").on("keyup", function() {
        checkFormat($(this));
    });
    $("#addDashField").on("paste cut", function() {
        var $inputField = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            checkFormat($inputField);
        }, 0);
    });

    function checkFormat($inputField) {
        var currVal = $inputField.val();
        var regexFormatPattern1 = /^(.)$/;
        var regexFormatPattern2 = /^(.)([^\-])/;

        if (regexFormatPattern1.test(currVal)) {
            $inputField.val(currVal.replace(regexFormatPattern1, "$1-"));
        }
        else if (regexFormatPattern2.test(currVal)) {
            $inputField.val(currVal.replace(regexFormatPattern2, "$1-$2"));
        }
    }
});
```

Some key points:

- handles keystrokes or pasting (`Ctrl-v` or menu selection)
- handles `delete` and `backspace` keystrokes
- handles inserting the "-" character in the middle of a longer string of characters (e.g., the user types in 5 characters and then goes back and deletes the inserted "-")

**Note #1:** there are two regex patterns, because the `.replace` method handles needs the correct number of captured groups, based on the length of the input.

**Note #2:** the `paste` and `cut`event needs a delay to handle the menu based pasting (which can sometimes fire before the text is entered into/removed from the field).

---

**UPDATE:** If the "cut/paste" functionality is not needed, you can simply leave out that event binding.

Comment: When you try to delete the whole string with backspace, and reach the hyphen it's hard to delete it.

Comment: @EnobaSistemas - yeah, that's definitely a trade off . . . the problem with ignoring backspaces/deletes, when processing the key events, is that it will allow you to delete the added "-" and will only re-add it after you've typed in a second character (e.g., type "1" gets you "1" --> auto-update get you to "1-" --> delete "-" gets you to "1" --> type "2" gets you to "12" --> auto-update gets you to "1-2"). That experience is inconsistent with the "add a '-' after the first character is entered' experience, so it's really a choice between which experience you think is better for the user.